# connection.recv not able to read the buffer

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, recv

server.py

```
while True:
        if buffer_len >= 100:
            connection.sendall("something")
        else:
            buffer_read = connection.recv(10)
            buffer_len = buffer_len + len(buffer_read)
```

In the client, I have sent a request (length = 100) and received a response once. But when I sent the second request, the `"buffer_read = connection.recv(10)"` line not giving any output. Seems like it is waiting for something to be written in buffer(infinite loop). So, my question:

1. why is conn.rev(10) waiting even though the client has written its request to the buffer?
2. Is it to do with asynchrony? should the client send its request before the server starts waiting?

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: Here is the client code

```
for tcp in Q
    self.sock.sendall(tcp.payload)
    buffer_len = 0
    while response_len > buffer_len:
        data = self.sock.recv(self.buff_size)
        buffer_len += len(data)
```

Comment: I don't think that this can be answered w/o seeing the client code too. And no, the client does not need to send before the server is waiting.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Added the client side code

Comment: This code is missing too much context to be actually useful, i.e. it references variables set somewhere else etc. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And it is not obvious from your code that the client has actually send a second request as you claim - it might still be waiting to recv more data from the server. It might be helpful to add some print statements to your code for debugging in order to see what part of the code is actually executed on each side.